# How do I number equations like (A.1) (B.1) and not (1) (2) in appendix?

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

I want the numbering of the equations to be like the numbering in chapters (Nºchapter,Nºequation) but instead of the number of the chapter it has the letter of the appendix section. Is it possible?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\appendix

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\chapter*{Appendix}

\section{One}

\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}

\section{Two}

\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}

\section{Three}

\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also add `\counterwithin{equation}{section} ` after your redef. This auto resets equation each time section changes and additionally redefs the look of the equation counter to include the section counter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same as the comment from user `daleif`, the [`amsmath` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) has a pre-defined command for that (`\numberwithin`), see `Chapter 3.11.1 Numbering hierarchy` (as of Version 2.1).

### Update

- Better use `\counterwithin{equation}{section}` as recommended by user `egreg` in the comments to this answer.
- List item `\counterwithin` has less dependencies (less surprises), according to reputation millionaire `egreg`.
- Initially, `\counterwithin` was part of the [`chngcntr` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) but is now part of the LaTeX core. Meaning, that as of time of writing, the documentation of the [`chngcntr` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) is still a valid source of information.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath} % Needed for \numberwithin but not for \counterwithin.

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
% https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
%   3.11.1 Numbering hierarchy
% \numberwithin{equation}{section} % <-- Previous solution
\counterwithin{equation}{section} % <-- Now recommended
\chapter*{Chapter Name}

\section{One}

\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}

\section{Two}

\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}

\section{Three}

\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With a fairly recent LaTeX release, I'd use `\counterwithin{equation}{section}`

Comment: @egreg Thanks, is there a benefit or is it more about being canonical?

Comment: The latter, as it introduces less dependencies. Also there are `\counterwithin*` (that doesn't change the representation) and `\counterwithout`.

Comment: @egreg Done, I am on my phone atm and therefore have limited patience editing the answer :).

Comment: @egreg Can you give me some kind of official reference to `counterwithin`? For example, when it was introduced to the LaTeX kernel (not sure if I use the right terminology)?

Comment: `texdoc ltnews28` shows that it was added in April 2018; the documentation for the package `chngcntr` is still valid, although the package is no longer needed.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I will update the answer later today or tomorrow.

Comment: @egreg Done. let me know if you are not happy with my joke (calling you reputation millionaire).

Comment: Who wants to be a millionaire? 